# Javascript assistance with Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/). I'm really not a Javascript person but I can't get this to do even the most basic of things.

In the developer console I get the following -

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

Is that what is causing my problem or is there something wrong with my bit of HTML/ Javascript?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
   <meta name="description" content="Sigmas Graph Example">
   <meta name="author" content="Dave">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="sigma.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <script>
      function myFunction()
      {
         var sigRoot = document.getElementById('sig');
         var sigInst = sigma.init(sigRoot);
         sigInst.addNode('hello',{
            label: 'Hello',
            color: '#ff0000'
         }).addNode('world',{
            label: 'World !',
            color: '#00ff00'
         }).addEdge('hello_world','hello','world').draw();
      }

      if (document.addEventListener) {
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction, false);
      } else {
          window.onload = myFunction;
      }
   </script>
      <div id="sig"></div>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not an error on your code. That is coming from the library your using code (sigma.min.js) . It's a harmless error that won't effect your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few tricks to getting the sigma rendering canvas initialized.

A few things to note:

- You add edges and nodes to the "graph" attribute of the sigma instance, not the instance itself.
- You need to specify an x and y for each node.
- Each node is a javascript object which should have and 'id', 'x', and 'y', and optionally 'color', and optionally other data associated with the node.
- Similarly for edges, each edge should have an 'id', 'source', and 'target'
- After adding edges and/or nodes, you need to call sigInst.refresh(), not draw()
- There are myriad options you can set with an "options" object when creating the instance.
- You need to set the size of the target div, or else you won't be able to see anything (at least on Chrome).

So, here is a working version based on your script above.  You will also note in the docs there are other methods for bulk import of nodes and edges, such as graph.read().

```
<div id="sig" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
  function myFunction()
  {
     var settings = {
        defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148',
        defaulLabelColor: '#99f',
        defaultEdgeColor: '#aaa',
        edgeColor: "default", 
        labelSizeRatio: "1",
        labelThreshold: 1,
    };
    var sigInst = new sigma({
      container: 'sig',
      settings: settings
    });
     sigInst.graph.addNode({
        id: 'hello',
        label: 'Hello',
        color: '#ff0000',
        size: 5,
        x:0,
        y:0
     });
     sigInst.graph.addNode({
        id: 'world',
        label: 'World !',
        color: '#00ff00',
        size: 10,
        x:1,
        y:1
     });
     sigInst.graph.addEdge({
      id: "helloworld",
      source: "hello",
      target: "world",
     });
     sigInst.refresh();
  }
  if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction, false);
  } else {
      window.onload = myFunction;
  }
</script>
```

Hope that helps.